# Не видит модели Yii2 RESTFull API

Tags: php, yii2, rest

Я создал апи в отдельной папке, все как описано в документации. Но когда я пытаюсь использовать модель `User`, которая лежит в `common\models` мне выдает ошибку, что не может ее найти.

С чем это связано? Модель есть точно

Comment: Код в студию, расположение файлов в студию. "Модель есть точно": я вам не верю, раз вы пишете "выдаёт ошибку, что не может найти" (ну я-то ладно, но вам даже ваш компьютер не верит). И не верю, что сделано всё, как описано в документации. Приводите конкретные ссылки на документацию, приводите код: без кода в вашем вопросе могут помочь только телепаты. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Проблема вызывана опечаткой или не вопроизводится -> на закрытие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в файле `api/web/index.php` не было прописано

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');
```